# No view found for id for ShooksFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to all this fragments stuff, and I get an error that couldn't be solved by any of the StackOverflow's questions.

My problem is that I'm getting the error of

> No view found for id 0x7f0c0078 (com.shook.android.shook:id/shooksLayout) for fragment ShooksFragment{1a77ec43 #0 id=0x7f0c0078

when trying to add a fragment dinamically.

My code:

MainActivity

```
...
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_friends) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Find friends!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shooks) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ShooksFragment fragment = new ShooksFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.shooksLayout, fragment);

        transaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_prizes) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get prizes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share your shooks!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
...
```

ShooksFragment

```
public class ShooksFragment extends Fragment {

public ShooksFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shooks, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ShooksFragment newInstance() {

    ShooksFragment fragment = new ShooksFragment();

    return fragment;
}

}
```

fragment_shooks.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.shook.android.shook.ShooksFragment"
android:id="@+id/shooksLayout">
```

Comment: Firstly, you should do `ShooksFragment fragment = ShooksFragment.newInstance();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
transaction.add(R.id.shooksLayout, fragment);
```

is incorrect because `R.id.shooksLayout` is defined in the layout of your `fragment`. The `id` you specify in `add()` should be the `id` of a `ViewGroup` you specify in your `setContentView()` fot the activity. For example, for my fragments I usually keep an empty `<FrameLayout>` in my activity and then provide the `id` of this container in both fragment `add()` and `replace()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ShooksFragment fragment = ShooksFragment.newInstance();
transaction.add(R.id.shooksLayout, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: This actually helped too! Thank you so much, but I think the other answer was more useful!
Thanks anyway

Comment: Don't have enough reputation :|