# Fragment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006f

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was trying to move from one Fragment to the second Fragment.
It shows the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c006f (com.chinatown.wangjian.chinatownbang:id/viewpager) for fragment TwoFragment{10598077 #1 id=0x7f0c006f android:switcher:2131492975:1}
```

This is my first Fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scrolling, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



        return v;
```

My second Fragment like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
```

Am I coding this correctly?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332955/no-view-found-for-id-for-shooksfragment/39333117#39333117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it seems that you are applying 2 layouts.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scrolling, container, false);
    //why setContentView?
    //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });



    return v;
```

Comment: thank you that's correct. I just copy content of Oncreate forgot to comment setContentView. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you as per your code you are not calling second fragment from first one.

Add this code into your first fragment like this

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//CREATE OBJECT OF FRAGMENT WHERE YOU WANT TO GO
fragment_2 frag2=new fragment_2();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frag2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Thats how you can launch next fragment from one fragment and you also calling two layout in your fragment it would be better if you use above code plus use only 1 layout for Fragment